# Is there a way to automate incrementing a Meteor package version?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In short, I'm looking for a command similar to `npm version patch` (or a clean way to do the same programmatically).

I'd like to do this as part of a build/test/deploy script for the package. Since `package.js` is JavaScript and not JSON, I'm not sure that there's a trivial way to automate this. I could rely on a `sed` command, but that seems a little fragile so I wanted to see if there was a better solution out there.